# How to include all results from a select if one specific result is present

Tags: sql

I am using 3 tables.

- Table1 - stores information about orders.
- Table2 - stores information about the products in those orders
- Table3 - stores detailed information about  the products

Below is the query that I use.

```
    select Table1.OrderNumber as Ordernummer,
        Table2.Productnumber as ArtikelNummer,
        Table3.Productdescription as ArtikelOmschrijving,
        Table2.Amount as Aantal,
        Table2.SellingPrice as PrijsPerArtikel from Table1
            INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.OrderKey = Table1.OrderKey
            INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.ProductNumber = Table2.ProductNumber
    where Table3.ProductDescription > any (select ProductDescription from table3 where ProductDescription like '%stock%') and
table1.OrderNumber in ( 
*ALotOfOrderNumbers*
)
```

With this part I am trying to select every Product in an order if that product has the word `'stock'` somewhere in the description.

```
Table3.ProductDescription > any (select ProductDescription from table3 where ProductDescription like '%stock%')
```

However this does not return the results that I want. It also returns orders, from  the orders that I put in, that do not have any products with the word stock in their descriptions. As I am quite new to SQL I feel like I am missing something basic here but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Kindly add sample data for all 3 tables and your desired output to your question

Answer (score 0):

> > I am trying to select every Product in an order if that product has the word 'stock' somewhere in the description.

So why

```
where Table3.ProductDescription > any 
        (select ProductDescription from table3 where ProductDescription like '%stock%')
```

then and not

```
where Table3.ProductDescription like '%stock%'
```

Is this already the answer you are looking for or is it not really products with 'stock' in their description you are looking for, but something else you failed to explain?

(With your WHERE clause you are looking for all products that come later in the alphabet than the first 'stock' description. I.e. If there exist two 'stock' descriptions: 'bstock' and 'ystock', you'll get 'ystock' and 'xxx' and 'zzz', but not 'bstock' and 'abc', because there is no 'stock' description before them.)